# Why ValidateRequest exist on .NET if data is encoded by the framework?

Tags: c#, .net

Every time I come back the data to the user, I see that .NET automatically encode data, to prevent malicious script.

So why ValidateRequest?

Comment: .NET isn't doing the encoding - a well behaved browser running non-malicious code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to asp.net: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation this method is used to prevent some script-injection attacks  .. the network is full of attackers so you should encode the data even if .NET automatically do it

Comment: ? Can you give an example where .NET will fail on encoding? (and maybe once where it won't with ValidateRequest).

Comment: check this link : http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/07/22/bypassing-validaterequest-in-asp-net

Comment: or download this pdf file it has everything you want to know : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.procheckup.com%2Fvulnerability_manager%2Fdocuments%2Fdocument_1258758664%2Fbypassing-dot-NET-ValidateRequest.pdf&ei=0_d7T5O9EtSW8gPoxIydDQ&usg=AFQjCNHKAR0_WOMCzARewWsRqsuoVtklpA&sig2=lDY3XR_5T__i3VGtJ-J4CQ

Comment: But I don't mind how crack ValidateRequest. I mind why there is this control! If I wrote <script>alert("ciao")</script> on a text area, in the postback it has been encoded. Yes, of course if it come from .NET literal...

Comment: also, the problem here http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/07/22/bypassing-validaterequest-in-asp-net is not by validation, but I think it's a bug by SQL Server : if I write `%uff1c` SQL server must save it as `%uff1c`, it shouldnt encode it automatically :O. Or, at least, it should encode `%uff1c` by the encoding choosed by admin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009177/validaterequest-fault-or-sql-server-bug