# ValidateRequest fault or SQL Server Bug?

Tags: sql-server, validation, xss

I was reading this [article](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/07/22/bypassing-validaterequest-in-asp-net). It says :

> That character is represented at the value %uff1c. If this value is passed to a varchar field in a SQL database, it will get converted to the real < character. I have not seen this work on a nvarchar field

Well, I think this is a SQL Server bug, not a ValidateRequest hack! If I write `%uff1c`, SQL Server must save it as `%uff1c`. Or, at least, it should encode "again" `%uff1c` by the charset choosed by admin.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, but a feature (but you cannot use it).

The point of the article is: if you want to post a string containing a '<', convert each < to a ＜ (Unicode codepoint FF1C) to avoid a validation error.

SQL Server receives a Unicode character string containing ＜ and tries to process it. If the data type of a table column or procedure parameter was Unicode-enabled (NCHAR, NVARCHAR, 2 bytes per character), no conversion would take place, and SQL Server stores the original value.

If the value is passed to a VARCHAR (1 byte per character) column or variable, however, the character ＜ (2-byte codepoint) is transformed to a <. Extending AakashM's code to illustrate:

```
DECLARE @nv nvarchar, @v varchar
SET @nv = N'＜'
SET @v = '＜'
SELECT @nv, @v, CONVERT(varchar, @nv)

＜   <   <
```

But, since this is the 21st century, and databases should be able to support every standardized language and symbol and character, there are very few scenarios left that justify using VARCHAR data.

Comment: +1 although this feature does have considerable consequences for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server cannot store ＜ in a `varchar` field. What would you like to happen in this situation:

```
DECLARE @v varchar(1)

SET @v = '＜'

SELECT @v
```

(note that that ＜is not the usual left angle bracket character, but rather the Unicode character with codepoint `FF1C`).

The result of the above will be `<` (the usual left angle bracket character). If you want to say this is a bug, you should say what your *expected* result is.